# Is there a way to see my complete Oyster card travel history online?

Tags: london, tfl

I have been using the same (visitor) travel/Oyster card to on TfL for several years and would like to see my full history for all my visits to London. I know there is a way to see at least recent history for my card use at ticket kiosks on the Tube system in London, but I would like to see all of it, and without having to visit London to do so, really to download to for analysis.

Is there a way to see my complete Oyster card travel history online? Can I download it?

Comment: You can open an online account to manage your Oyster card, and you will have access to your travel history, but that’s limited to the last 8 weeks. Not sure if there’s a way to go beyond that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Creating an account](https://oyster.tfl.gov.uk/oyster/link/0004.do) for an Oyster card will only show you the past eight weeks of travel. After this eight week period, the data is anonymised. However, if the card has been irregularly used, [there may some older data on the card itself](https://tfl.gov.uk/corporate/privacy-and-cookies/oyster-card), according to TFL:

> We retain data about the individual journeys made using your Oyster card for eight weeks after the card is used. After eight weeks, the journey data in the ticketing system is disassociated from your card (ie anonymised).  This eight-week period is considered reasonable to enable customers to verify or make enquiries concerning their journeys (for example, for refund purposes).
>
> Customer names and contact information associated with a registered Oyster card will be retained for two years after the card was last used or had a season ticket or pay as you go credit added.
>
> Some journey information is also stored on the Oyster card itself; this comprises the last eight journeys and related charges, up to three season ticket products, (generally the most recent three tickets, including future dated), and the last two incomplete journeys. If you are an irregular user of your Oyster card, the data stored on the card may be older than eight weeks.

Answer (score 5):

As other answers have said, you need to sign-up for an online account at https://oyster.tfl.gov.uk/

As other answers have said, the TfL website does not retain the journey history permanently.

However, **you can download journey history statements** in .csv or .pdf.

Better, if you want to avoid having to download journey history statements manually, you can **subscribe to have weekly Oyster journey history statements sent to you by electronic mail**, in .csv and/or in .pdf (very useful if submitting expense claims for business travel). That way, so long as you do not lose your electronic-mail account, you will have a complete history of weekly statements online via your electronic-mail provider.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can get about ten months of history by logging into the Transport for London website, if you have an account for your Oyster card.  (My Oyster cards have been active since September, 2007.)

It is quite possible that TFL might have more records on file for law enforcement or other purposes, but it may take special effort to acquire such records, if they exist.

https://tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/oyster/oyster-online-account is the web page for accessing your account.

Comment: That's interesting as I can only see journeys from the last eight weeks as the other answer suggests. Perhaps you have special status.

Comment: @mdewey There is a drop-down that lets you see prior periods.  The oldest period on mine is from March, 2017.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie are you sure you're looking at Journye and payment history for an *Oyster* card, not a *contactless payment card* ?

Comment: @AakashM Yes indeed.  It even nagged me to upgrade to a second-gen Oyster card.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to access that outside the UK.

Comment: @orome I'm in Canada, so it can't be an inside/outside the UK issue.